# Is std::clock() broken on MSYS2's g++ compiler?

Tags: c++, clock, msys2

I'm trying to write a simple single header benchmarker and I understand that `std::clock` will give me the time that a process (thread) is in actual use.

So, given the following simplified program:

```c++
nt main() {
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    auto start_cpu = std::clock();
    auto start_wall = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    // clobber();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    // clobber();
    auto finish_cpu = std::clock();
    auto finish_wall = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cerr << "cpu: "
        << start_cpu << " " << finish_cpu << " "
        << (finish_cpu - start_cpu) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " s" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "wall: "
        // << FormatTime(start_wall) << " " << FormatTime(finish_wall) << " "
        << (finish_wall - start_wall) / 1.0s << " s" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Eqne6oM4o)</kbd>

We get the following output:

```
cpu: 4820 4839 1.9e-05 s
wall: 1.00007 s
```

I just want to clarify that the `cpu` time is the time that it executes the code that is not actually the `sleep_for` code as that is actually done by the kernel which `std::clock` doesn't track.  So to confirm, I changed what I was timing:

```c++
int main() {
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    int value = 0;
    auto start_cpu = std::clock();
    auto start_wall = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    // clobber();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        srand(value);
        value = rand();
    }
    // clobber();
    std::cout << "value = " << value << std::endl;
    auto finish_cpu = std::clock();
    auto finish_wall = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cerr << "cpu: "
        << start_cpu << " " << finish_cpu << " "
        << (finish_cpu - start_cpu) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " s" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "wall: "
        // << FormatTime(start_wall) << " " << FormatTime(finish_wall) << " "
        << (finish_wall - start_wall) / 1.0s << " s" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GKP6WT14G)</kbd>
This gave me an output of:

```
cpu: 4949 1398224 1.39328 s
wall: 2.39141 s
value = 354531795
```

So far, so good.  I then tried this on my windows box running MSYS2's g++ compiler.  The output for the last program gave me:

```
value = 0
cpu: 15 15 0 s
wall: 0.0080039 s
```

`std::clock()` is always outputting 15?  Is the compiler implementation of `std::clock()` broken?

Comment: `srand(value); value = rand()` is determenistic and can be calculated at compile time.

Comment: *"MSYS2's g++ compiler"* Which one? They ship like 6 of them: `gcc`, `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`, etc. What compiler flags?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, `g++ (GCC) 11.3.0`. Seems I've installed `gcc`, `mingw-w64-i686-gcc` and `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, hmmm. Seems that was the issue.  I read in from `/dev/random` and the values are more intelligent.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, I'm surprised that I didn't get something similar from godbolt though even with `-O3`. https://godbolt.org/z/33bao1W84

Comment: The two compilers use different C runtimes with completely different implementations of `rand`. It doesn't make sense to compare them. Use `std::random` facilities or some custom workload instead.

Comment: no problem here. gcc 12.2.0 in msys2.  if you increase the loop count by 100x does it make a difference?

Comment: I also set loop count using `std::cin` before start_cpu and in my test, start_cpu changes on actual input time so `std::clock()` is good in msys2.

Comment: @Chris.C Ah, the issue is that the resolution on the MSYS2 g++ compiler is 1000x less than on godbolt. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I assumed that `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` would be the same.  However, on the MSYS2 compiler, it was 1000x less then on godbolt.org.